# Stack overflow when no tail-recursion optimization in scala?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I'm building a scala compiler from the scala compiler source code by myself. In the source code of compiler, there are many tail-recursion functions/methods. Building scala compiler from its source code also requires compile the source code of compiler itself. If I add the option `-g:notailcalls` to turn off tail-recursion optimization during compiling the source code, a statck overflow error will arise when running the built compiler.

In one word, is it possible that in a big and complex scala program which has many recursive calls, leaving out the tail-recursion optimization when compiling can cause stack overflow error at run time?

Comment: Definitely, you can check the [issues](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9048?jql=text%20~%20%22stackoverflow%22)

Comment: Yes, of course. Turning off tail-recursion optimisation means recursive calls of otherwise tail recursive functions consume a stack frame when they didn't before, so taking up more stack and making a stack overflow more likely.

Comment: It doesn't require a "big and complex" program. Just try it: `def f(i: Int): Int = if (i == 0) i else f(i - 1); f(1000000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. But please note Scala is able to figure out if the function is tail recursive by itself, you don't need to pass the `@tailrec` annotation to the function.

However, scala is unable to transform a suitable function to its tail-recursive form. You have to do that manually, but not every function can be transformed in that way.